# When did the last meeting between Rama and Hanuman occur?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

I am asking this question **according to the Valmiki Ramayana only**.

AFAIK, Hanuman and Rama had a meet during the coronation of Rama for the last time.

But, did they meet after that according to Valmiki Ramayana? When was their last meeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When is their last meeting?** [as per Valmiki Ramayana]

Lord Rama and Hanumana met on the day when Lord Rama departed from the earth (i.e. last day of his incarnation):

> Having thus addressed the king of Rakshasas always obeying Raghava s command, Kakuthstha said to Hanuman "It is settled that thou shalt live forever, do thou, now observe thy promise. As long as my history shall run current in this world do thou at my command live happily." Being thus addressed by the high souled Raghava Hanuman attained to great delight and said: As long as the sacred theme shall pass current in this world I shall live here carrying out thy commands. ~ [Uttarakanda of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-121)